# max() and count() sql

Tags: mysql, sql, subquery

I have these tables :

```
Customers ( cid , cname ) 
Products ( pid , pcolor)
Reservations ( pid , cid , date)
```

I need to know what color is the product which has been reserved the most times , and so far I wrote this:

```
      SELECT p.color, count(p.pid) as j
      FROM products as p , reservations as res
      WHERE p.pid = res.pid
      GROUP BY p.color
      ORDER BY j DESC
      LIMIT 1
```

Now this query works good , but there's little problem , if there are 2 different products with 2 different colours that were reserved the same number of times it gives me just one of them(because of the "LIMIT 1") .. what can I do?

Comment: Is pid <-->pcolor one to one relation ?

Comment: yes it is one to one!

Answer (score -1):

```
SELECT pr.pcolor, count(pr.pid)
FROM Products pr
JOIN Reservations res
ON pr.pid = res.pid
GROUP BY pr.pcolor
```

Comment: this is exactly the same code as op, with different aliasing.

Comment: maybe that was caused by posting the answer at the same time?

Comment: I mean you have exactly the same code as the **question**, except for aliases.

Comment: As you can notice in the question history, the original question was edited. Check the very first version of the question. As I did not receive such notification of change, I could not edit my answer. Therefore your down vote is non sense.